# How to accept revisions / track changes (ins/del) in a docx?

Tags: java, xslt, ms-word, docx4j, wordml

In MS-Word 2010 there is an Option under File -> Information to check the document for problems before sharing it. This makes it possible to handle track changes (to new newest version) and remove all comments and annotations from the document at once.

[image]

Is this possibility available in docx4j as well or do I need to investiagte the corresponding JAXB-Objects and write a traverse finder?
Doing that manually could be a lot of work since I would have to add the `RunIns` (`w:ins`) to the `R` (`w:r`) and remove the `RunDel` (`w:del`). I also saw a `w:del` once inside a `w:ins`. In this case I don't know if this also appears vice versa or in deeper nestings.

Further research brought this XSLT up: 
https://github.com/plutext/docx4all/blob/master/docx4all/src/main/java/org/docx4all/util/ApplyRemoteChanges.xslt
I was not able to run this within docx4j but by manually unzipping the docx and extracting the document.xml. After applying the xslt on the plain document.xml I wrapped it in the docx container again to open it with MS-Word. The result was not the same as it would be by accepting the revision with MS-Word itself. More concrete: The XSLT removed the deleted marked text (in a Table), but not a listing dot before the text. This appears quite often in my document.

If this request is not posible to solve in an easy manner, I will change the constraints. It is sufficent for me to have a method for getting all text of a ContentAccessor, as a `String`. The ContentAccessor could be a `P` or `Tc`. The String shall be inside a `R` there or inside a `RunIns` (with `R` inside of that) For this I have a half solution below. The intersting part starts in the line of `else if (child instanceof RunIns) {`. But as mentioned above I'm not sure how nested del/ins Statements might appear and if this will handle them well. And the results are still not the same as if I would prepare the document with MS-Word before.

```
//Similar to:
//http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/how-to-get-all-text-element-of-a-paragraph-with-docx4j-t2028.html
private String getAllTextfromParagraph(ContentAccessor ca) {
    String result = "";
    List<Object> children = ca.getContent();
    for (Object child : children) {
        child = XmlUtils.unwrap(child);
        if (child instanceof Text) {
            Text text = (Text) child;
            result += text.getValue();
        } else if (child instanceof R) {
            R run = (R) child;
            result += getTextFromRun(run);
        }
        else if (child instanceof RunIns) {
            RunIns ins = (RunIns) child;
            for (Object obj : ins.getCustomXmlOrSmartTagOrSdt()) {
                if (obj instanceof R) {
                    result += getTextFromRun((R) obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result.trim();
}

private String getTextFromRun(R run) {
    String result = "";
    for (Object o : run.getContent()) {
        o = XmlUtils.unwrap(o);
        if (o instanceof R.Tab) {
            Text text = new Text();
            text.setValue("\t");
            result += text.getValue();
        }
        if (o instanceof R.SoftHyphen) {
            Text text = new Text();
            text.setValue("\u00AD");
            result += text.getValue();
        }
        if (o instanceof Br) {
            Text text = new Text();
            text.setValue(" ");
            result += text.getValue();
        }
        if (o instanceof Text) {
            result += ((Text) o).getValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: For text extraction, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/TextUtils.java#L138

Comment: I'd be inclined to try using XSLT to accept changes rather than JAXB traversal.  I thought there was code to do this somewhere, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: For XSLT, there is https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/WordprocessingMLPackage.java#L223  Note this transforms the Flat OPC representation, so it also has access to other parts (eg Styles part).   It would be straightforward to write something which just transforms the Main Document Part.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee836138(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Is that the link you meant? https://github.com/plutext/docx4all/blob/master/docx4all/src/main/java/org/docx4all/util/XmlUtil.java
I could not get it working.
I am not fimiliar with writing complex XSLT.
As far as I understand your msdn link, an flat OPC representation is no problem. 

My software reads a .docx file, indicates specific headlines and corresponding tables. The data from the tables is extracted line by line (and column by column) and stored into my own datastructure. After that there is no draw back into the docx.

Comment: But the input document has various amounts of tracked changes. My routine was to accept these changes with MS-Word before loading the document with docx4j. But I hoped for a more convenient way. In tried to take care of the RunIns with a simple If-Statment, but is seems not to work properly. What would be the "best" way to achieve this? For your link https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/WordprocessingMLPackage.java#L223 I miss a description of the transform-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/309a8e4008553452ebe675e81def30aab97542a2?w=1 adds a method for transforming just one Part, and sample code to use it to accept changes.

The XSLT is just what you found (relicensed as Apache 2):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:WX="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint"
  xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core"
  xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
  xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.xmllab.net/wordml2html/ext"
  xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  version="1.0"
        exclude-result-prefixes="java msxsl ext o v WX aml w10">


  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="/ | @*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:del" />

  <xsl:template match="w:ins" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You'll need to add support for the other elements identified in the MSDN link.  If you do that, I'd be happy to get a pull request

Comment: thanks so far! Could you provide me with a JAR-File containing these changes? I use maven to get the newest docx4j version. It seems to be rather complicated for me to get the new code into my project this. I will see if I am able to improve this XSLT.

Comment: you can install to your maven repo by downloading the source code, then running mvn install, then  mvn install:install-file (you'll need various args)

Comment: I was not able to install the two files alone, but I build a .jar with mave myself now. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754589/exchange-class-file-in-maven-dependeny-with-fixed-java-in-eclipse).

I tried the existing xslt with a new word document, and it worked in a simple example. But my productive docx brings up an error: `WARN org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler .handleEvent line 88 - [ERROR] : unerwartetes Element (URI:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006", lokal:"AlternateContent"). Erwa`. I added the xmlns:mc into the xslt but nothing changed.

Comment: If you post another question referencing the transform method and copy your comment explaining what happened, I'll answer there.

Comment: See now https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/8e726967667cd31cd2519d0785a9156f48e2fbbe?w=1   You can either download  https://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20170821.jar then use mvn install:install-file  or you can pull changes and run mvn install

Comment: As for today, I stopped diging into this. Using the PowerTools in C# seems to be far mor convinient. But before that I encountert an issue that I like to share. It seems that the referenced documentation "Accepting Revisions in Open XML Word-Processing Documents" is outdated. They give algorithms for accepting changes in the structure of tables. In my test Word 2010 and newer did not record any changes in the structure of tables such as merging cells or deleting them. Word even prints a warning about that.