# Exchange class file in maven dependeny with fixed java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to exchange one file in a maven dependency (docx4j) using Eclipse. So no command-line tools for maven is installed right now.

I have a two `.java` files which I downloaded manually from github that should overwrite two `.class` files. And I would like to achieve this without re building the whole project.

Another perspective:

There are source-code changes for a library in a github repository that are not published in a released version on maven central. And there is no JAR file provided. But I want to use these changes in my project that gets its dependencies though maven. And I would like to avoid going into the deployment process of the framework itself.

I read in [how to edit .class file in Maven dependency in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099790/how-to-edit-class-file-in-maven-dependency-in-eclipse) that it is not possible without rebuilding the project. But I got the hint in [How to accept revisions / track changes (ins/del) in a docx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544974/how-to-accept-revisions-track-changes-ins-del-in-a-docx/45602281?noredirect=1#comment78304182_45602281) that it is possible using `mvn install:install-file`. But a [Maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) also just talks about JARs to exchange, not a single .java File that should replace a .class file.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtefact</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>myName</name>
    <description>myDescription</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        [...]
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: A .java file cannot replace a .class file directly. The code needs to be rebuilt to generate the new class file from the java source.

Comment: But to build the .class out of the .java I need to create a new project, reproduce the package structure and include all inherited classes, right?

Comment: When you say you need to replace class files with java files, what exactly do you mean? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I use docx4j in my project. The framework itself and its dependencys are managed with maven (see my pom.xml). JasonPlutex was so kind to help me with an issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544974/how-to-accept-revisions-track-changes-ins-del-in-a-docx/45602281?noredirect=1#comment78304182_45602281) and commited a changed file in his github repo. But these changes are not in maven-central right now. So I want to use this code changes in my project. And I hope that I don't have to download his whole project from git to create a new .jar on my side.

Comment: Thee repo with the changes I mentioned: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/309a8e4008553452ebe675e81def30aab97542a2?w=1

Comment: You could ask JasonPlutex to publish this beta version to some remote repository and then fetch the jar directly from it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what your problem with "downloading the whole project" is. I see a `pom.xml`, so it should be as easy as downloading [docx4j-master.zip](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/archive/master.zip), unpack it and run `mvn install`. Now docx4j is available in your local repository, so you simply have to adjust the version in the `pom.xml` of your project.
There are other solutions which are closer to your suggestion, but these are true hacks. This is by far the cleanest and future proof.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me into trying it that way. It was indeed very simple. Never the less a more direct solution would be great. Maybe someone comes up with a solution for this in the future.

Comment: More direct? Then you must ask the team to publish doxc4j to a repository. With this solution you don't have to wait and as you said it yourself, it is really that easy.

Comment: No, I meant direct in the meaning of the original question. If someone has the same issue and might not be able to build the whole source code, he might be glad to read one of those "hacky" solutions you mentioned.

Comment: This is the answer, but it is not an advice! If you have the sources, do it as I told you. If you only have classes, copy them to src/main/resources, maybe combined with relocation via maven-shade-plugin. But from that moment on a simple dependency upgrade of docx4j is not possible anymore.